# Copy/paste screenshot runtime error 91 vba in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the runtime error 91. What my code does is take a screenshot from Excel file and paste it in an Outlook email. Not really sure on how to fix this issue.. please help

```vb
Sub CreateEmail()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("O5:AN41")
    r.Copy

    'Open a new mail item
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'Get its Word editor
    outMail.Display
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    'To paste as picture
    wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture 'here is where I Get the error 

    Dim shp As Object
    For Each shp In wordDoc.InlineShapes
        shp.ScaleHeight = 70
        shp.ScaleWidth = 70
    Next

    With outMail
        .To = Range("B35").Text
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("A6").Text
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, instead copy/paste here and format with the Code Tags (`{}`).  Also, see [the Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660298/picture-pastes-over-text-in-outlook-mail-using-excel-vba), i.e. narrow down the Range.

Comment: I tried to copy my code but it wouldn't let me post it

Comment: Try again. Screenshots are not acceptable. If you're trying to copy several thousand lines of code, that's a problem. Reduce your question to a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem you're facing.

Comment: it should be good now

Comment: That code looks very close to the [official docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector#example), with the `If Not wordDoc Is Nothing` check removed - if `wordDoc` is `Nothing` for whatever reason, a member call against that object would raise error 91 like you're getting. Not sure why it would be `Nothing` though.

Comment: If you haven't already, try [adding a reference to the Outlook library](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/add-object-library-reference-vba/). You would scroll down the list until you see `Microsoft Outlook xxx Object Library`.

Comment: I have the Library Added for outlook and Ward

Comment: It may be because the Outlook VBA enumerations are not available in Excel, try replacing wdChartPicture with 13, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype

Comment: "The WordEditor property is only valid if the IsWordMail method returns True and the EditorType property is olEditorWord." - have you tried checking these properties?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor

Comment: yeah I dont think the WordEditor or the wdChartPicture is the issue

Comment: Your posted code works fine for me (Win10/Office 365)